# How do I remove the IOS 7 update on my phone?

Tags: ios

How do I remove the Ios 7 update on my phone? I've been having problems with my 4S since it was installed such as not being able to connect to Wifi and unable to send emails.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't saved SHSH blobs from earlier iOS you cannot downgrade the iDevice.
Apple is signing only the newest versions of their OS so if you dont't its too late.
Try to recover the system using itunes. Google has very much info about how to enter recovery mode and use it. It will restore clean, newest iOS for you.